# ListBox DataTrigger for IsSelected == False firing upon population?

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, listbox

I'm having a problem with a ListBox, but it involves a few custom controls. I will give a short and long description of the problem.

### Short Version

I have a ListBox that is populated with several items by setting its DataContext. The behaviour of these items is partially tied, via a Trigger to the IsSelected property. It seems that whenever the ListBox is populated with items (DataContext is set), the IsSelected property is explicitly set to false for all of the items in the list, which causes the trigger to fire for each item. I was expecting each item to have IsSelected as false by default and not having the trigger fire for each item. Is this the expected behaviour of ListBox?

### Detailed Version

Here is what I am trying to achieve: A custom ListBox (SequenceNavigator), containing what I'm calling a ThumbnailViewer as the ListBoxItems. The ThumbnailViewer shows an image and also has one (or more) IconOverlayButtons overlayed on the image. IconOverlayButton, as the name suggests, is a Button that is represented by an icon (DrawingBrush on a Rectangle). The IconOverlayButton should only be shown for the selected item in the list and it should fade and and fade out.

I almost have this working, but am running into a problem. To notify that IconOverlayButton to fade in/fade out, I have set triggers in the ListBox like so:

```
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type s:SurfaceListBoxItem}}}" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="uiThumbnailViewer" Property="Mode" Value="{x:Static local:DisplayMode.Playback}"/>
                        ...
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type s:SurfaceListBoxItem}}}" Value="False">
                        ...
                        <Setter TargetName="uiThumbnailViewer" Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
```

I have then, in turn, set the ControlTemplate of the IconOverlayButton to react to the IsEnabled property changing values:

```
<UserControl x:Class="...UIIconOverlayButton"
         ...>
<Grid>
    <Button>
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle Opacity="0" x:Name="rctIcon"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="rctIcon" Property="Fill" Value="{Binding Path=ButtonDownBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:UIIconOverlayButton}}}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="rctIcon" Property="Fill" Value="{Binding Path=ButtonUpBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:UIIconOverlayButton}}}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard FillBehavior="Stop">
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rctIcon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                 From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:1" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.Setters>
                            <Setter TargetName="rctIcon" Property="Opacity" Value="1"/> 
                        </Trigger.Setters>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard FillBehavior="Stop">
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rctIcon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                 From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.25" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

This solution is 90% working. When I select a ListBoxItem (ThumbnailViewer), the IconOverlayButton fades in correctly and when I select another item, the previous one fades out and the selected one fades in.

PROBLEM: When the ListBox is populated, it appears that IsSelected is being explicitly set to False for each item (not by me, as far as I know). This triggers the ExitAction portion of the IconOverlayButton's DataTrigger, causing the IconOverlayButton to appear momentarily and fade out for every item in the list. This is of course not desirable behaviour. I was hoping IsSelected would be false by default for the new items, hence no trigger.

EDIT: Updated title to be more accurate. Also, I tried this with ListBox/ListBoxItem instead of SurfaceListBox/SurfaceListBox item and the behaviour is the same. The Surface SDK does not appear to be a problem here.

Comment: Can we see the code for the IsSelected property?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure which code you're referring to. Those triggers are in the ItemTemplate of the ListBox (actually, SurfaceListBox from the Surface SDK, but I believe these are more or less the same for this purpose). As far as I know, I am not modifying the IsSelected property in code behind - it is a property of ListBoxItem (or SurfaceListBoxItem).

Comment: does this happen with a normal ListBox?

Comment: @jberger Good question - I switched from SurfaceListBox/SurfaceListboxItem to ListBox/ListBoxItem and the behavior is the same (as I expected).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set up your trigger as a `MultiDataTrigger`, and use the `IsLoaded` state as one of the triggers.  This will prevent the trigger from firing before the control is loaded.  There are a few key modifications to achieve this.

First, you'll need to modify this Trigger :

```
<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
```

...changing it into a `MultiDataTrigger` :

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="True" />
        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type my:actionButton}}, Path=IsLoaded}" Value="True" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
....
```

`my:actionButton` is the UserControl (you want to look at its `IsLoaded` property).  I use a `MultiDataTrigger` specifically because `IsLoaded` isn't a dependency property, and therefore requires a `DataTrigger` or `MultiDataTrigger`.

Not done yet!  Since `IsLoaded` isn't a dependency property, you'll have to notify the UI from codebehind when it's updated.

```
    public actionButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(actionButton_Loaded);
    }

    void actionButton_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Notify("IsLoaded");
    }
```

This should fix your problem!  As a disclaimer I can't guarantee it's the BEST solution, but I've tried to pick a reasonably clean one.

Edit : Notify :

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void Notify(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Question - is the Notify method tied to the INotifyPropertyChanged interface? That's what I assumed, but just want to confirm.

Comment: So I just tried this and it works beautifully - thank you! I usually resort to StackOverflow when I'm totally stumped, so I don't think I would have figured this out on my own. I agree it would be nicer to have a cleaner solution, but the more I work with WPF, the more I find that a "clean" solution is not always possible.

Comment: Yup, Notify is just a standard "Notify on this string" with INotifyPropertyChanged.  Added code.

Comment: I'd argue that it's fairly clean way of doing things if I didn't have to notify IsLoaded inside the Loaded event... I'd have thought it'd do that itself ;)  So close but so far.

Comment: Agreed, it's not a hack by any stretch. It's probably the next best thing to a xaml-only solution.